# How do I subract results from different functions from each other in Python?

Tags: python, list, math, operators, subtraction

I have a function that I've written out and would like to perform mathematical operations on it, the same way I can with numbers.

For instance, with the code below, I would like to take Sup(3) - Sup(2) = result, but this doesn't work. Can I take functions that I've defined and perform mathematical operations on them, the same way we can perform mathematical operations on numbers (i.g, 2 * 2 = 4)?

For n = 2, my result is 1.083
For n = 3, my result is 1.717 using the code below.

```
def Sup(n):
    mylist = []
    for n in range (2,2**n+1):
        Su = (1/n)
        mylist.append(Su)
    #print(mylist)
    print (sum(mylist))
```

When I attempt this operation, I get the following error:

```
---> 12 Sup(2)- Sup(3)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'neType'

What does this mean?
```

Comment: `Sup` doesn't return anything. Try `return sum(mylist)` instead of `print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can I take functions that I've defined and perform mathematical operations on them, the same way we can perform mathematical operations on numbers?* 
Yes you can, assuming that your functions return numbers.

*What does this mean?*
As pointed out in comments, it means that your function doesn´t return anything. Adding `return` to your function should do the trick:

```
def Sup(n):
    mylist = []
    for n in range (2,2**n+1):
        Su = (1/n)
        mylist.append(Su)
    #print(mylist)
    print (sum(mylist))
    return sum(mylist)
```